# Is there a standard format for plant community composition data?

Tags: ecology, database, data, community-ecology, vegetation

FIA has a [nice database of forest Inventory data](http://www.fia.fs.fed.us/tools-data/docs/pdfs/FIADB_user%20guide_v3-0_P2_06_01_07.pdf), this would be great except that it does not seem capable of handling data from non-tree species (e.g., grasslands, wetlands).

Is there a standard database or flat-file format for collecting plant community data (e.g., biomass, cover, dbh as appropriate)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There does not appear to be a current standard, but [Veg-X](http://wiki.tdwg.org/Vegetation/) is a standard that has been developed to facilitate exchange of plot-based vegetation data, and may provide the closest to what you are looking for.

Veg-X is described in [Wiser et al 2011](http://labs.bio.unc.edu/Peet/pubs/JVS-VegX.pdf) and the project home page is http://wiki.tdwg.org/Vegetation/

From the abstract:

> The exchange standard for plot-based vegetation data (Veg-X) allows
>   for observations of vegetation at both individual plant and aggregated
>   observation levels. It ensures that observations are ﬁxed to physical
>   sample plots at speciﬁc points in space and time, and makes a
>   distinction between the entity of interest (e.g. an individual tree)
>   and the observational act (i.e. a measurement). The standard supports
>   repeated measurements of both individual organisms and plots, allows
>   observations of entities to be grouped following predeﬁned or
>   user-deﬁned criteria, and ensures that the connection between the
>   entity observed and taxonomic concept associated with that observation
>   are maintained.

---

Wiser, S.K., N. Spencer, M. De Caceres, M. Kleikamp, B. Boyle, & R.K. Peet. 2011. Veg-X -- An international exchange standard for plot-based vegetation data. Journal of Vegetation Science 22:598-609.